# Google Chrome won't install. Help?

Tags: 12.10, software-installation, google-chrome, downloads, google

I downloaded Chrome from the official page. Once it was done downloading, I double clicked it to start the installation. It took me to Ubuntu's SoftWare Center, and I clicked "Install." Once I clicked that, the very beginning chunk of the orange bar always appears, but then just stops for no reason.

Help please?

Comment: I'd use Chromium. It's in the official repositories and it's open source.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be you have downloaded the .DEB file . we can install it with Software center If you want GUI way and we can install it with terminal also.

IF you want to install from terminal then open your terminal with CTRL+ALT+T then cd to where you have downloaded that chrome .DEb file then do

```
sudo dpkg -i <wrtie here the file name of your google chrome without glides>.deb
```

this is the way to install.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue, this is what I do, first install it via terminal (sudo dpkg -i google*.deb), wait few second, and the installation will fail and it ask for some repair, now double click the DEB file to open Software Centre, it will offer to repair and continue to install Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem... solved with this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1674679

Installing .deb install package... look up for this package and you should be good...

Best Regards

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the things listed above I personally still ran into some issues so here is what I did to get it installed and running smoothly when the ubuntu software center and the Gdebi package installer both failed me.

I added the PPA to the repository by typing the following commands in the terminal:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then you need to type:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
```

Next to update it:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then to install the stable version of Google Chrome type:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

After the installation completes you should have the latest version of Google Chrome installed and working. Cheers and hope this helps!

Comment: that is the same answer as here http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-14-04