# How to install Google Chrome

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

How do you install Google Chrome on Ubuntu?

Comment: Just install **Chromium**, the open-source (FLOSS) counterpart to Chrome. Basically Google develops Chromium, adds some proprietary features (and likely tracking features) to it and distributes it as "Chrome".  
So either install Chromium from the software center or just `sudo apt-get install chromium`. I think that's way easier to install!

See also: [What's the difference between Chrome and Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant)

Comment: ^ `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Comment: `sudo snap install chromium` for the snap inclined

Comment: Update: In 2020, the Chromium deb was replaced by a Chromium snap. A Chromium deb still exists, but it's not a browser -- it just installs the Snap. So most of the deb-related Chromium answers below are still valid. This change had NO effect on Chrome, which is still distributed as a deb from Google.

Answer (score 703):

**`google-chrome-stable`** is available on a 3rd Party Repository: [Google  Chrome](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome?dist=stable) (for Stable).

**Now that `apt-key add` is deprecated use this:**

1. Download Key:

   ```sh
   wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O /tmp/google.pub
   ```
2. Make a keyring for chrome:

   ```sh
   gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/keyrings/google-chrome.gpg --import /tmp/google.pub
   ```
3. Set repository:

   ```sh
   echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/google-chrome.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   ```
4. Install package:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
   ```

Follow the instruction for installation with `apt-key add`:

1. Add Key:

   ```sh
   wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Set repository:

   ```sh
   echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   ```
3. Install package:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
   ```

Comment: It appears that the package from Google adds the Apt source file now, but named "google-chrome.list". Attempting to do an apt-get update will complain about duplicates. If you rename to match, the issue doesn't occur.

Comment: @Pandya 3 years old but still a good instruction set! Google also provides an https endpoint for downloading. Probably this could be an update to this answer.

Comment: Same and confirmed in 2021 by https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome

Comment: Hmmm `E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable` in Ubuntu

Answer (score 260):

## [Video Demonstration](https://youtu.be/GY95dgBO6ho)

Go to https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/

[image: Screenshot: Chrome website]

Click Download and a small window will pop up with some download options.

[image: Screenshot: Chrome select package]

We want the ".deb" for Ubuntu. Make sure this box is checked.

> Note: Google no longer provides 32-bit versions for Linux - you are only able to get 64-bit versions for Linux as of at least February 2016

It will give you the option to "Open with..." or "Save File". The default option for "Open with..." is to open via "Software Install". Select this option.

[image: Screenshot: Opening deb dialog]

Give your PC a few moments and the ubuntu software center should open up with the .deb file you have downloaded ready to install. (I already have chrome installed) Click the install button and you will be prompted for your password to start the installation. This should take no more that 2mins to install.

Enjoy ;]

Note: Chrome will also be updated through the normal Ubuntu update process so you can expect to grab the latest version when Ubuntu updates.

[image: Screenshot: Google Chrome in Software Center]

Comment: this is weird ... I though that to get updates you'd need to add a repository ...

Comment: its adds the Google Chrome PPA when you install the package so from then on you get updates as they are released.

Comment: If you install things the Windows way, you get viruses.

Comment: For those looking for 32-bit chrome, here's a link to a torrent file containing a .deb file for the 32-bit version of google-chrome: http://payitforwardcash.com/google-chrome-32bit-debian.torrent  sha256sum: 168de6fe1f98ab00f73e8a370796b57a8977130ebde7e85ef4de7d8a7a695b93

Comment: Now what is the way to have Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit?

Comment: I tried this in Xubuntu 16.04, but it uses GNOME Software instead of Ubuntu Software Center. Installing the deb by GNOME Software did not work.

Comment: And where to find it after it is installed? It is not in PATH.

Comment: I do believe it installs under /opt/ in the root

Comment: @AdamF Right, users should be extremely cautious when installing software this way and do it only exceptionally.

Comment: Yes, it is in /opt, particularly /opt/google/chrome/chrome (it also creates chrome-beta and chrome-unstable in /opt). It adds itself to Dash and Launcher but you need to add it to PATH manually (that's a good thing I believe). @Bunyk

Comment: This method used to work fine for Ubuntu 14.04. I recently updated to Ubuntu 16.04 and I am not able to install google chrome. When I press the install button in software center, nothing happens.

Comment: But how would you get automatic updates?

Answer (score 142):

Or if you want the actual Google Chrome, open a terminal and follow:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

The 32-bit version is no longer available.

If you encounter any errors simply use

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

To run it from terminal use `google-chrome` or hit the super key and search `Google` or `Chrome`

Comment: This no longer works.   For one, i386 versions are no longer available.   Second,  the download links on Google's site are now broken.

Comment: The URL to the .deb file has changed, and is now: `https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Comment: Nice. Needed the apt-get portion to finish off the dependencies needed by the chrome package.

Comment: This is the best and simplest answer from the command line, without needing to use another browser to download. Worked perfectly in 18.04, without needing any additional dependencies.

Comment: I got an error when trying to run, `[20264:20264:0201/211304.449159:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.`

Answer (score 21):

Google Chrome is different from Chromium.

[What's the difference between Google Chrome and/or Chromium? What are the advantages/disadvantages to each?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant)

Chromium can be found in the Ubuntu Software Centre. To download Google Chrome however:

1. Goto: https://www.google.com/intl/en-CA/chrome/browser/
2. **Click** <kbd>Download Chrome</kbd>
3. Choose either `32 bit .deb`(for 32bit Ubuntu) or `64 bit .deb` (for
   64bit Ubuntu)
4. **Click** <kbd>Accept and Install</kbd>
5. Download **.deb** file to a folder (**Downloads** is the default folder)
6. Open up your **Downloads** folder.
7. Double-click the **.deb** file you just downloaded.
8. This should launch **Ubuntu Software Centre.**
9. When it prompts you to whether you wish to install Chrome, just say yes.
10. Input Password when asked to install.

Answer (score 8):

When installing the debian package, if you have errors of the sort:

```
packages have unmet dependencies
```

or

```
package <package-name> is not installed
```

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The above will install the packages that were not installed but are needed for the debian package.

Now, you should be able to install the debian package via:

```
sudo dpkg -i <google-chrome>.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try saving the below script into a file and running it:

```
if [[ $(getconf LONG_BIT) = "64" ]]
then
    echo "64bit Detected" &&
    echo "Installing Google Chrome" &&
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb &&
    sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb &&
    rm -f google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
else
    echo "32bit Detected" &&
    echo "Installing Google Chrome" &&
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb &&
    sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb &&
    rm -f google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
fi
```

It will automatically detect your architecture and install the proper version of Google Chrome for your system.

[Script source here](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr)

Comment: Again, this is unnecessarily complicated for the everyday user to install Google Chrome with... It's just making things harder than they need to be.

Comment: And yet if it was hosted somewhere and he gave a one line Curl command, then it would be exactly how lots of people work.

Comment: @GregoryOpera Is copy paste enter really all that complicated?

Answer (score 2):

Hello people of the Ubuntu Universe, I wrote a c++ program for installing google chrome 64 bit, Pandya's answer is very similiar. I usually write programs to handle anything, that I think I might have to do again in the future! Consequently installing google-chrome is something I've done many times.

If you do not already have build-essential installed as dependency, or c++ (g++) development you must install it first:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
```

Next copy the following program from this post into gedit and save it as googGt.cpp
(change your tab width to 4):

```
//************************************************************************
// This googGt.cpp is created to install the google-chrome web browser
// on Ubuntu 14.04 lts 64 bit.
// author@GWade
//************************************************************************

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

void PrntGoogPpa(ofstream& googPpa);

void PrntGoogGtr(ofstream& googGtr);

void PrntGoogLst(ofstream& gogLst);

int main()
{

    cout << "Creating the script that adds google-chrome PPA\n" <<endl;

    // create the googPpa.sh shell script
    ofstream googPpa;

    googPpa.open("googPpa.sh");

    PrntGoogPpa(googPpa);

    googPpa.close();

    cout << "Changing the mode of access to executable on the script\n" << endl;
    // change mode of access to executable
    system("chmod +x googPpa.sh");
    cout << "Excuting and installing the Google-Chrome Web Browser\n" << endl;
    system("./googPpa.sh");

    // create an ofstream object and call the function
    cout << "Creating the script that installs google-chrome\n" << endl;
    ofstream googGtr;
    googGtr.open("googGt.sh");
    PrntGoogGtr(googGtr);
    googGtr.close();

    cout << "The googGt.sh script has been created\n" << endl;
    cout << "Changing the mode of access to executable on the script\n" << endl;
    system("chmod +x googGt.sh");
    cout << "Excuting and installing the Google-Chrome Web Browser\n" << endl;
    system("./googGt.sh");

    system("rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list");

    ofstream googLst;
    googLst.open("/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list");
    PrntGoogLst(googLst);
    googLst.close();


}
void PrntGoogPpa(ofstream& googPpa)
{

    googPpa << "#! /bin/bash\n\nUPD=\"updatedb\"\n" << endl;

    googPpa << "wget -q -O - "
            << "https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub"
            << " | sudo apt-key add -" << "\n" << endl;

    googPpa << "echo \"deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main\""
            << " >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list\n\n$UPD\n\nexit" << endl; 

}
void PrntGoogGtr(ofstream& googGtr)
{
    googGtr << "#! /bin/bash\n\nAPGTN=\"apt-get install\"" << endl;

    googGtr << "APUPD=\"apt-get update\"\nUPD=\"updatedb\"\n" << endl;

    googGtr << "$APUPD\n\n$APGTN google-chrome-stable -y\n" << endl;

    googGtr << "$UPD\n\nexit" << endl;

}
void PrntGoogLst(ofstream& googLst)
{

    googLst << "### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###" << endl;

    googLst << "# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications"
            << " may be lost." <<endl;

    googLst << "# deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" <<endl;

}
```

Its nothing spectacular just some function abstraction. Its pretty easy to follow.
Once you've copied and saved the program compile from command line:

```
:~$ g++ googGt.cpp
```

This create an a.out in the working directory. Next gain root privledges and execute the program.

Gaining root privledges:

```
:~$ sudo bash
```

Executing the newly created binary:

```
:~# ./a.out
```

The process is pretty straight forward first add the google PPA, then it updates the
software sources, then it installs google-chrome, and last but not least it comments out the google-chrome.list url addresses so it doesn't update the 32 bit version as well as 64 bit on subsequent apt-get updates. You will now have the scripts 1) the script that adds the googPpa.sh and 2) the script that installs google-chrome (googGt.sh).

GO UBUNTU!!

Comment: Far too technical for the "Everyday Joe"/"Everyday Sally"... The "usual" method - as described below (with pictures) - is the easier way to install Google Chrome.

Comment: May I ask why don't wrote a shell script? Using c++ for that looks weird since are only executing shell commands.

Comment: Hey, why don't you write a script to install build-essentials first?