# Wrongly installed google chrome 32-bit version, what can I do now?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, google-chrome, deb

I downloaded google chrome 32-bit version deb file

and then use ubuntu software center (following [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-14-04))

but it doesnt work

then I noticed that I made a mistake in downloading the wrong version

so I downloaded the 64-bit version

however, I can't install this deb

why?

and I tried

```
    sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    [sudo] password for nanger:
    (reading database ..。)
    Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking google-chrome-stable (39.0.2171.99-1) over (39.0.2171.99-1) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
     google-chrome-stable dependence on libappindicator1；but：

    dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
     dependence problem - not configured
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
    Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
    Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
    Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
    Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
    errors：
     google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: did you uninstall old 32-bit version of chrome ?

Comment: @ARUL I did the installing, but it seems that it is not successfully installed

Comment: the question showing 64-bit version, please update how do you installed 32-bit version

Comment: @ARUL I downloaded 32-bit version deb, and install it using software center

Comment: the go to software center, search for chrome if installed click *Remove*

Comment: @ARUL: I would say that's an answer, so Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby I posted as answer....

Answer (score 1):

First you have to remove chrome 32-bit already installed, for that go to *Ubuntu Software Center* and search for *chrome*. When you find it select it, and you can see *Remove* option.

By clicking remove you can remove the unwanted version, now you can install needed 64-bit version.

Easy way to install Chrome 64-bit version *.deb*, open with *Ubuntu Software Center* and click *install*.