# Chrome Flash Player Extension Keeps Bringing Up Black Bar 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-chrome, flash, globalmenu

Hi there I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and am trying to watch cartoons while I do some work (I have it running through a second monitor). I am watching out of the Google Chrome native client. Every time I go full screen and focus on another task, the launcher and the unity global menu at the top of the screen keep appearing. While I seem to have figured out a fix for the launcher (just take the launcher away in the display settings) is there a fix for the  unity global menu and for the full screen to remain in focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im sorry to hear this, ;< im very sorry but you can not get unity WP for linux/ubuntu/gentu/etc. you can not get unity WP for linux, not even with wine. if you want to watch anime ( i hope these are the cartoons you are watching you can watch them at this website but it will only work with firefox. if you go to the ubuntu software centre and search "flash player plugin" download it and if you go into firefox and go to settings then plugins you will see flash player. these are 2 websites you can watch anime/cartoons  http://www.crunchyroll.com/
 you can copy and paste it into your browser. heres the other one. http://www.hulu.com/tv/genres/anime i hope i helped you :>P

Comment: Moreso Archer and Rick and Morty but I like anime as well. So you're saying that Chrome does not offer this support but Firefox does eh?

Comment: yes that is what im saying if you go to chronium(if u use that because you cant get chrome on linux,etc) and install the plugin from ubuntu software centre it will not work for chronium but it will for firefox. ever since i did this i would stay up till idk 3 am and watch anime all night. i hope i helped you if i did please let me know ASAP

Comment: ...you can get Chrome on linux...I'm running it right now. But matters aside, thanks for the clarification that appears to be that Firefox is the browser to be running flash files out of. I will now probably reinstall firefox and just run it as a separate process.

Comment: your right you can get chrome but it is called chronium

Comment: There's Chromium (The open source version) and then there's normal Chrome (which I like because it's prettier). http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: oh! Thank You i was not aware of this!!! ( no sarcasm)