# google-chrome-unstable icons not found on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, icons, gnome-classic

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on a Toshiba Satellite C50-B-14D and I am using it with the gnome classic metacity window manager. I then added the Google repositories on the sources directory in `/etc/apt` following the instructions from this answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/510186/17702

After installation, I run `google-chrome-unstable` from my Alt+F2 menu, and everything works fine, except the icon is not found at the bottom of the screen. See screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas how to get it to show the icon?

Answer (score 1):

Google-chrome is famous for its problems with `.desktop` files and their icons, especially if you had an other version installed before.

Since you installed it from a `.deb` file, an icon must be installed. Most certainly, there must be an old, outdated or incorrect `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` causing the "disconnection".

Local `.desktop` files "overrule" global ones, therefore, if there is a local `.desktop` that does not "match" (the current version of) a globally installed application, a variety of symptoms can occur. An iconless appearance is one of them.

#### What do do

Since you technically don't need local `.desktop` files of a globally installed applications (unless you want do make modifications to its behaviour), you can safely remove all `.desktop` files, referring to `google-chrome`, in `~/.local/share/applications`. Simply browse to the directory and remove all `.desktop` files of `google-chrome` or webapps, calling `google-chrome`. Then log out and back in and run the application again to see if it is fixed.

If you are having doubts on a specific `.desktop` file, make it executable to make it show its icon and the correct "interface" name (as defined in the line `Name=` inside the `.desktop` file).

Comment: It turns out there were a bunch of `.desktop` files there. I removed them with this command `rm ~/.local/share/applications/chrome*.desktop`, then logged out and back it, but still no icon.

Comment: @719016 Please see if there are multiple chrome `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`. Probably there are, but if not, please make the `.desktop` file executable and see if it shows its icon.