# Ubuntu Software Center doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, google

I am new ubuntu user. I wanted to download Google Chrome, but something happened and now when I go to Ubuntu Software Center it is automatically closed after 1 second. Then I see the error:

> E: The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Open a terminal , run the following commands, and post the output `sudo apt-get update && sudo install -f`

Comment: This link should help you: http://askubuntu.com/a/510186/367165

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't come from the Software Center. You need to download and install it from chrome.google.com. Installing the DEB should also fix the Software Center,

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq google-chrome-stable
```

This might do the trick

Comment: They haven't installed it yet. Some explanation of a `sudo` command would be appreciated.