# System keeps getting hung - Flash error

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I open firefox and browse through sites. Sometimes, automatically, the cursor stops moving, I can't use the keyboard too and system is hung. It doesn't go to the command line either. I found out that this may mostly be due to a adobe flash plugin. I don't know which one or which one to remove.

Every time this happens I have to manually force shutdown the computer and switch it on again.

I know I've been pretty vague in giving details but I don't know how exactly this problem occurs.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You resolve problems by trying one thing at a time

**Is flash the problem?:**

- disable flash in Firefox

  - go to firefox/tools > addons > plugins and set shockwave flash to ask to activate
- does the problem still exist?

**Is Firefox the problem?**

- install another browser

  - [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)
- does the problem still exists?

Good luck!

Comment: I think disabling flash will work. I'm trying that now.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem on 2 different machines I disabled flash on one of them and the problem seemed to go away. Will do the other tomorrow. IMO I think that either Fire Fox is buggy or its the Flash plugin either way it makes for a terrible experience you should not have to disable a plug in to make it stable