# Error message (popping up 5 times) when doing apt-get update

Tags: 14.04

I had typed `sudo apt-get update` and got this message.

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite self-explanatory. If you want to use the current CD-ROM as a source for updates you need to add it explicitly; for this, type

```
sudo apt-cdrom add
```

If you don't want to use CD-ROMs for updates, either remove by hand any reference to the CD-ROM from the APT sources (files `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`), or do that from the GUI by following Mostafa's suggestion:

> Go to **system settings > software & update** and uncheck CDROM as a source for update.

Comment: I tried to 'uncheck CDROM as a source for update.' . But surprisingly this is showing 'failure of internet connection' with this message. W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: If all other packages are updated fine, your sources.list references an incorrect repo for Google Chrome.  Follow the instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome

Comment: I don't even use Google Chrome. I access net through Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: You can just remove the reference to that repo then.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: Delete the lines referring to Chrome from files `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. Then do `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **system settings > software & update** and uncheck CDROM as a source for update.