# How to watch cnn go using browser?

Tags: stream

I have directv and i used to watch cnn live on my browser in windows. since making the switch to ubuntu, i can watch it. I have install flash and extras. I have tried all browsers. It just doesnt work in ubuntu. Help please. I have already tried every suggestion in previous questions asked.

Comment: Which browsers have you tried? Did you try [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Google Chrome, which I assume you did not try. You may have tried the open-source browser Chromium, but that doesn't have flash etc. that Google Chrome has, which is needed for CNN Go. You can install Google Chrome using these excellent instructionsn:

[How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)