# I cant install Google Chrome on Ubuntu | Can't run file

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, debian

I want to install Google Chrome on Ubuntu but I am not been able to do so.

I know there are answers for my question on other posts but they didn't solve my problem.

Problem is that after I download the google chrome for Debian/Ubuntu but when I click install, nothing happens.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Here is my installation screen pic!]

And when i try `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` shows: [image]

And Here is my downloads folder where chrome is present but Ubuntu doesn't detect[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Google Chrome?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Comment: It doesn't help. I searched for that post before posting my post. I don't know what's the problem!

Comment: I tried ElefantPhace answer. It does download the google chrome using 
`cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

But it does not install. Even this command does execute but useless 
`sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Try marking the file as executable in the permissions.

Comment: Please, no screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. And it says no such file or directory. Where did you download the file to?

Comment: @mchid I did but its useless

Comment: go to directory it say that's no such a directory

Comment: try `sudo dpkg -i "drop the .deb file"`

Comment: @muru and MohammadSalma it is in Download's directory. I even copied it in tmp folder but no use

Comment: If it is in the Downloads directory, then do `sudo dpkg -i Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`.

Comment: @muru it again says no such file or directory. The file is there but this Ubuntu can't find it

Comment: @MohamedSalma your code is giving error for file not found

Comment: Error !!! how you try i just say `sudo dpkg -i` then press space then **drag and drop your file** if working that's ok if not download the file again

Comment: for the last screen shot rename file delete the last **.** after **.deb**

Comment: @MohamedSalma thanks for effort but it gives error and says install needs at least one package archive file argument

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First Install Gdebi by

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

After installing `gdebi` try installing google-chrome with `gdebi`

you can use `gdebi` to install deb file in terminal or graphical

in terminal way you can install the deb by sudo gdebi   in your case it is

```
sudo gdebi google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

If the file is in your downloads folder, run this instead:

```
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/google*
```

If the file is in `/tmp` run this instead:

```
sudo gdebi /tmp/google*.deb
```

GDebi will automatically resolve any dependencies and install the deb file

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but it says file not found. I have uploaded the pic of my google chrome also where it is present but I am wondering why Ubuntu is not detecting the file

Comment: Yes it worked hurray!!!!!!!!!!!!! `sudo gdebi /tmp/google*.deb` command worked. I think it was in tmp folder. 

Thanks to all of experts

Comment: @Ninja I updated the answer for you, run this command:  `sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/google*`

Comment: @Ninja There was a period at the end of the file name in your downloads directory that should not have been there.

Comment: @mchid Thanks for the effort the above command worked this one `sudo gdebi /tmp/google*.deb` I think chrome was in the tmp folder

Comment: @Ninja Yes, and it was also in your downloads directory as well. The problem was that the file was not named `~/Downloads/google*.deb` it was named `~/Downloads/google*.deb.` The file in your `/tmp` directory did not have the extra period at the end of the file name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear @mchid and others. I wish I had the authority to upvote your answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: pure terminal**

You were in your home directory (indicated with `~`) in the terminal window. However, the file is located in `~/Downloads` directory. So write `sudo dpkg -i Downloads/goo` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It will complete the filename (if it’s not ambiguous – and it *won’t* be ambiguous in your almost empty Downloads directory).

**Option 2: involving GUI interactions**

Another option is to write `sudo dpkg -i` and drag the file from Nautilus into Terminal window. This should fill in the full path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not very particular about the Chrome then you can also try Chromium Browser. It is available in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: i didn't even mind having Firefox but actually it was our assignment and our instructor said us to Install the Google Chrome :)