# Problem with installing chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried to install Google Chrome by downloading a `.deb` file from the internet.

I opened it using Software Center, but I get a message:

> This is 3rd party software and it may have non-free components

More importantly, it's not installing.

Comment: Which have you installed, 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Google Chrome?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

To install Chrome, you must be running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu. Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run the following:

```
sudo apt update
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f -y
rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt update
google-chrome
```

Comment: There is no need in the last three commands.

Comment: They're not strictly required, but the last three get rid of the now-unnecessary installer, update Apt with the Chrome repository information (which it didn't have before), and start Chrome to make sure it was installed properly.

Comment: @Olathe isn't the command to start Google Chrome `google-chrome-stable`? I believe it is, but I don't use Chrome anymore.

Comment: I checked, and it looks like both `google-chrome` and `google-chrome-stable` work.