# Can't install Google Chrome ("This software comes from a 3rd party")

Tags: google-chrome

It has happened with other things that I wanted to install also.

It shows a box with: "This software comes from a 3rd party and may contain non-free components".

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you get any error messages?  Posting them would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it: 'This software comes from a 3rd party and may contain non-free components'.

Comment: That's not an error message.

Comment: Why would that message prevent you from installing Chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Google Chrome?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Comment: The point is that I can't install some stuff. I wrote the info I get every time I try to install something and I have done everything suggested in the responses I've read, but it is clear that I must be missing something. 
I'll keep looking. 
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Enable *Canonical partners* and *Canonical Partners (Source)* in *Software and Updates* in the tab titled *Other Software*, select *Reload* and retry to install Google Chrome or other third party software.

Comment: Thank you, I did that but I have the same result.

Comment: Google Chrome is not made available via Canonical Partners. (Skype is.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also install Google Chrome by navigating to https://chrome.google.com, clicking "Download > For Personal Computers  ", and selecting "`.deb` for Ubuntu".

Wait for the download to complete, then open the `.deb` file and enter your password when you're prompted. Hopefully, Chrome will install as normal, and may even be eligible for `apt` updates.

Answer (score 0):

So, like Cat said, download the appropriate Chrome .deb file from:

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

Then navigate to your Download folder, right click on the .deb file and open it with the “Gdebi Package Installer”.  It is really slick and will install Chrome with no problems.

If you haven’t installed the “Gdebi Package Installer” you can easily get it from the Ubuntu Software Center.  Gdebi has come through for me in a lot of instances where everything else has failed.  It just works.

Luigi Luigi

Comment: Done that, but did not work. Never mind, I am using another browser. :)