# Software center not installing softwares

Tags: software-installation

Softwares can not installed through software centre, message appers untrusted softwares even if chrome

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome is not in the default Ubuntu repositories. Instead there is an open source version of Chrome without Chrome's built-in proprietary flash player called Chromium Web Browser (chromium-browser) in the default Ubuntu repositories.

For instructions on how to install Google Chrome from the terminal see [How to install Google Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome).

In order to test if the Software application is working properly, try installing a little application called *hello* and give it a try.