# "Trying Ubuntu" Can't install programs! Help!

Tags: software-installation

I'm a brand new user to Ubuntu and need some help installing programs. I can't get them to install and I don't know why. I download them from their websites, such as google chrome download, but after that I can't do anything. I'm starting to think it's because I'm "Trying Ubuntu". Is this true? Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: What did you attempt for i.e. installing Chrome?

Comment: Are you running from a live USB or CD?

Comment: See [How to install Google Chrome?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Comment: You can install applications while "trying" ubuntu just like you normally would (although the performance might not be as great, depending on the size of your flash drive and how much RAM you have). I would guess your issue stems from the fact that software doesn't work the same way in Windows and Linux.  You can't install Windows built software in Linux and vice versa. You need to use the version built specifically for the platform you are using.

Comment: Here's the issue. I would like to do it via software center. I can't because it's not available or not on my PC. I don't know why, but when I try and install it through the terminal, I get this: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

**For most applications**:
Click on the Ubuntu Software Center icon (see below) to install applications. You should rarely, if ever, download software directly from the internet, with Google Chrome being the notable exception. The main reasons for using software from the software-center are stability, security, and compatibility, since it has programs that are built specifically for Ubuntu.

[image: Ubuntu Software Center]

**For Google Chrome**: You need to download the .deb file from the Chrome website [64 bit .deb (for Debian/Ubuntu)]. It will end up in your Downloads folder. Open Files (Nautilus), go to Downloads, and double-click the .deb file. It will open Ubuntu Software Center and install your program.

[image: Files Icon]
[image: Downloads Folder]
[image: Google Chrome Installer]

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to install applications in Ubuntu for me is by opening a terminal and type. Sudo apt-get install application name