# how to install qemu-kvm in ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, qemu

while installing qemu-kvm i'm getting error like below :

```
$sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package qemu-kvm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  qemu-user:i386 qemu-user

E: Package 'qemu-kvm' has no installation candidate
```

can anyone help me how to fix that issue and install qemu-kvm?

Comment: Which ubuntu you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qemu-kvm` is available in the `main` component of Ubuntu repository. I think, you might have disabled main source.

To enable `main` component

```
sudo apt-add-repository main
```

To refresh package index

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install it

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm
```

Hope that will fix

Comment: Thanks, that installed fine.. but while installing chrome im getting the same error.. can u plz guide me on this  $sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package google-chrome-stable is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'google-chrome-stable' has no installation candidate

Comment: @NvN for google chrome, check this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome