# Why can't I install google-chrome-stable with a script?

Tags: apt, bash, google-chrome, wget, sh

So I understand that the "right way" to get google chrome is to simply hit the button to download and install it from their web page. That said I like the idea of having all my basic setup requirements in a script so that if I ever have to start on a fresh install of Ubuntu I can simply run that script and have all my favorite software. That said when I took the bash commands listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) and put them in a script (as seen below) running the script as sudo user did not result in google-chrome-stable installing... What gives?

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
apt-get update 
apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y
```

I ran the script by typing it's fully qualified location into the terminal.

Comment: How did you run your script? What commands did you use to run it? You could be missing a shebang in your script.

Comment: What happened when you ran the command? What errors did you see? Please [edit] your question and clarify. And why are you using `sh -c ' echo . ..  ` instead of just `echo ...`?

Comment: try `wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

If you get errors, use `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: The trouble is that I have already installed it at this point by jsut bashing the commands through terminal rather than running the script, I am really just trying to better understand why it didn't work as is. The Nuances between writing something line by line into the terminal and having the same the verbatim in a script are still a bit beyond me. Thanks for the input though! I'm curious, why do you think changing directory would help? I didn't think any of those commands were sensitive with the present working dir...

Comment: What error did your script give? How did you run it? Can't give much thought without knowing those.

I didn't realize that you were trying to install it via script, my answer was for classic shell installation.

Comment: No errors, I ran it and nothing happened.