# How Do I Play RuTube Videos in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash

I'm using Firefox browser. I navigate to [RuTube.ru](http://rutube.ru) and try to play a video. I get a message that says "can't load plugin". I'm sure this has something to do with Flash. How do I get these videos to play in Firefox?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 and latest Firefox updated via Ubuntu package manager.

Comment: Can you play video on YouTube?

Comment: @Liso YouTube uses HTML5 by default since a very long time. RuTube still requires Flash. As such, whatever happens in Youtube is irrelevant for the issue,

Comment: @JordanEvans Yes, you need to install Flash in order to use Firefox. Alternatively, install and use Google Chrome which comes with the latest Flash embedded.

Comment: @Liso I can play YouTube videos.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have Chrome installed. It cannot play the video either.

Comment: @JordanEvans Are you sure it's Google Chrome? Chromium does not come with Flash. Please check.

Comment: @CelticWarrior You're right. I have chromium-browser. I will look for Chrome.

Comment: @JordanEvans https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

Comment: @CelticWarrior, oops, I tried this (top answer), http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome, before I saw your answer. It gave me an outdated flash and the videos still didn't play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable [Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) and install the `adobe-flashplugin` package which installs plugins for both Firefox and Chromium.