# APT could not locate package chrome

Tags: apt

[image]

I am not able to use terminal to install Chrome and I am also having problems downloading from Ubuntu Software.

Comment: Chrome is not available in Ubuntu repo. You can install Chromium however using `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`. If you want to install chrome instead, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome).

Comment: @g_p I think you meant `chromium-browser`.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome is not available in the archives since it is proprietary software released by Google. You have two options:

- You can download Chrome for Ubuntu from here:
  https://www.google.ca/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html
- You can install [chromium-browser [image: Install chromium-browser]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser) from the archives, which is similar to Google Chrome but lacks a few things, such as the PPAPI Flash player