# How to install google chrome browser on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome

To be honest, I'm new to Ubuntu and 've heard that this OS more advanced rather than Windows. But why the installation of the simple browser became so complicated is out of my mind. So I downloaded google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb. After running `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` and after running `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64` and after running `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable` in the terminal nothing happens, but the message `Couldn't find any package by glob` and `Couldn't find any package by regex`. Trying to install it normally through UI brings Ubuntu Software window to a frozen state. Has anything might be done to install the browser on the Ubuntu? Tried to navigate to Downloads folder where my google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb is located and run `sudo apt install` command - didn't work. Terminal shows `Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with good old double click on the file ?

Answer (score 12):

Google chrome is not available in Ubuntu official software repositories, you can install `chromium` instead of Google chrome.

to install `chromium` run:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

And to install `Google chrome`, you should download its `deb` installer from [here](http://chrome.google.com). which you already did.

then to install it run:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

If you encounter to any errors related to dependencies; run:

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: The terminal says E: Unable to locate package gdebi. This might be some sort of configuration problem

Comment: In 16.04 and later, you can use apt to resolve dependencies without the extra step of installing gdebi: `sudo apt install /path/to/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Comment: @President are your source updated? I updated my answer ;)

Comment: @user535733 Cool, Didn't know about it... thanks. updated the answer ;)

Comment: Btw if you're unfamiliar with path writing, you can just open location where .deb file is located and right click "Open in the Terminal" option to open the path. There you only need to write `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Comment: @Egrimo I did everything possible to open the google chrome .deb file, but no success. Something is missing. Switching back to Windows OS

Comment: @President bad move  :). Did you install Chrome deb file again ? You can choose save file option while downloading and open the file using gdebi app. You can install it using `sudo apt-get install gdebi`

Comment: @Egrimo You'll be surprised but I started to read other posts on google / stackoverflow, and somehow I did installation of the google chrome. Seems like I was missing some dependencies, I run several commands in the terminal to update (still, I'm so new to Ubuntu that I don't even know what was updated :-). After update happens I noticed that google chrome installed normally with the $sudo apt install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Answer (score 2):

That is because .deb files are installed with a different command!

In order to install a package from a .deb file you should use the following command: 
`sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` in your case.

As I remember it, that's all installing chrome requires, that said, as a general fyi sometimes dpkg will not work the first time and it will inform you to run `sudo apt-get install -f`.  But after you do just that, you will be able to run dpkg -i again and it will work.

Comment: Well, the problem that terminal displays is "cannot access archive: No such file or directory." Do I need to provide some sort of full path to the .deb file? Like in windows with slashes? Not pretty familiar with Ubuntu

Comment: @President, yes you must provide the path to the package. The package manager is not psychic.

Comment: @user535733 After giving a full path to the google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb there is another error message appears in the terminal "dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable"

Comment: You downloaded a deb package that is incompatible with your release of Ubuntu. Don't do that. Delete the incompatible package, then read https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/

Comment: @user535733 So there is a place where I can actually pick up the correct release of the Chrome for my Ubuntu. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: @President - as mentioned in the answer, if you receive the error regarding dependencies when you first try to install, run sudo apt-get install -f to install the missing dependencies. Then run the sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb command again - and it will be installed correctly. The installation will also configure and enable a new official Google source for Chrome listed under System Settings > Software & Updates, Other Software, which will enable you to install updates as they are released.