# Flash player errors since most recent update

Tags: updates, flash

Since this mornings updates; I am unable to load flash player (Websites tell me it is either not installed or not activated).

It shows as correct version in Chrome Components and I have also installed latest flash version straight from the website but still have no luck.

Can anyone help?

Edit:

Current Version showing as Version: 26.0.0.137

Seems to be isolated to Chrome/Chromium, privacy settings are set to allow

Thanks,

Comment: If you are running, do you have the latest version of it?

Comment: Yep - Version: 26.0.0.137

Comment: The latest version is `59.0.3071.115`. Please update your Google Chrome.

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510186/119531) to install the latest version of chrome

Comment: I have the latest version of Chrome, the version I posted was for Flash Player. Any ideas?