# Can I use Intel True Key on Ubuntu?

Tags: intel

Does anyone have Intel True Key working on Ubuntu? If so, how?

On my computer, I got it to work for a while by installing [this hidden extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/true-key-by-intel-securit/nbeldjopgciegccabfohnefghfpinncn) into Chromium. But that method stopped working a while ago (I forget exactly when).

Comment: Fairly certain the answer may be no because of what platforms they support but not 100% sure

Comment: Indeed Linux has never been officially supported ever since True Key was first released. But it was working nonetheless, at least for a while. So at least there's a chance!

Comment: hidden Chromium extensions don't count as Linux support heh.  Just saying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Sept 2017, you can use true key on Ubuntu with either Firefox or [Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/a/510079/95361). At least, it works for me!

Instructions: Nothing tricky here. To install True Key into Firefox, you browse to the [true key website](https://www.truekey.com/) using Firefox and click the big "download" button! To install in Chrome, ditto using Chrome.

It does *NOT* seem to work on Chromium, only the actual [Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/a/510079/95361).