# Completely new to Ubuntu - need MATLAB installed

Tags: software-installation, java, chromebook, matlab

I found that you can install MATLAB, a MathWorks software, to Chromebooks if the Chromebook has an Intel (non-ARM) processor and you install Linux.

I've installed Ubuntu.

NetSurf didn't have Java enabled and I couldn't find how to enable it, so I tried to install Chrome... which didn't work.

So I took to forums and installed Software Center, but when I tried to install anything (Chromium), it said that I did not have permission/access to... I

spent the next few hours trying to figure out the GNOME software but when I installed it, NOTHING came up in the "applications" page.

**tl;dr:** I'm brand new to Linux and I couldn't even find the version of Ubuntu that gets installed onto Chromebooks.

I need to figure out how to download MATLAB, and that's it. I will use the Chrome OS for everything else, I just need Linux for MATLAB.

Is there anybody that could possibly walk me through, step by step, how to do this? I already know how to install Linux;

it's everything past that once I'm in Linux that I'm clueless about. I couldn't even get to the log in screen on MathWorks via NetSurf.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB Doesn't work?

Comment: I can't even log into mathworks from NetSurf and I couldn't figure out how to download another browser so I couldn't even get to that point. I'm also not sure how to install packages either...

Comment: Check this out for installing Chrome. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) As far as MATLAB, I really don't have a clue.