# How to install Google Chrome and WPS in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, google-chrome, wps-office

I am using UBUNTU 16.04 LTS. I have installed Google Chrome and WPS office by downloading the *.deb file and then using

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

It seems to install correctly without error. However when I try to launch them the icon is displayed on the launcher but the window doesn't come out.

Comment: Try this way, It worked f [Chrome Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Actually that seem to be a small problem with my system. It was detecting 2 displays - one the actual monitor and the other the installed graphics card. I found this solution on some forum. I had to turn off one of them corresponding to the graphics card and it started working fine.