# Fail to open Google Chrome Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, google-chrome

I have been following these instructions to install Chrome on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS machine

[How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Everything worked fine as far as I see but when I try to use chrome I receive the following error message

```
~$ google-chrome
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Any help on that?

edit --

```
~$ sudo google-chrome
[19256:19256:1103/123548.485046:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(88)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited the questio to show the output when I try to execute the command in root login

Comment: Did you try installing it using official deb file?

Comment: May I know out of [7 answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome), which one you followed?

Comment: What version of Chrome did you install (`google-chrome --version`)?

Comment: try sudo google-chrome --no-sandbox

Comment: Try reinstalling https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in a virtual machine / container?

Comment: Are you logged in as root ? Any errors from apparmor ? Any reason you are running chrome and not chromium (chromium  is the same thing, without the branding, and is in the repositories.