# Links clicked in Thunderbird won't open in Chrome unless browser is already running

Tags: google-chrome, thunderbird

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit), Thunderbird 52.4.0 (64-bit).

I'm having a problem with Chrome that only happens when I click on a link within Thunderbird.  If the browser is already started up, everything works fine.  If the browser is not already running, it appears that Chrome is opening - the Chrome icon lights up on the launcher - but the page never shows up.  This is what I've tested so far:

- Disabled all plugins, extensions, etc. in both Thunderbird and Chrome.
- Links open fine from other apps - LibreOffice docs, Cherry Tree, etc.
- If I set Firefox as the default browser, that works fine whether or not Firefox is running when I click the link.
- I have two different profiles in Thunderbird; the problem is the same regardless of which profile I load at startup.

Please note that this is **not** a problem with the default/preferred browser; it has only to do with whether Chrome is already open or not when a link is clicked in Thunderbird.

Even though this is not actually a preferred browser issue, I tried all the various suggestions I could find related to problems with the correct browser launching for Thunderbird links; none of them made any difference.  **In all cases, the settings worked as they should if Chrome was already open** when I clicked the link, **and didn't work if it wasn't open**:

- Changing network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http & .https to true, and then manually choosing Chrome when prompted to pick app to open link
- adding a user.js file specifying the browser to use
- Specifying Chrome as the app for http and https in Incoming Attachments

I'm at a loss.  I would be very grateful if anyone has any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this further.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to ever find the cause of this problem, but I was able to resolve it.  Incidentally, I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04 (for unrelated reasons), and that had no effect on the problem.

This is the process I followed; even though it didn't provide an answer for what was wrong, I am including here in case it helps anyone else who needs to troubleshoot a similar problem:

- **Made copies of both of my Thunderbird profiles**.
- **Purged Chrome and Thunderbird** (`$ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome*` and `$ sudo apt-get purge thunderbird`)
- **Re-installed Chrome first**; because of the prevalence of reported problems with Thunderbird recognizing Chrome as the default browser, I wanted to make sure Chrome was installed and set as default before installing Thunderbird.  I **used the install process described in [AskUbuntu question 510056](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)** (the first answer, written by Pandya; even though it is several years old, it is still applicable).
- **Re-installed Thunderbird** (`$ sudo apt-get install thunderbird`).
- **Tested using default profile**, configured only enough to allow me to access an email to test with.  **Test was successful**; link from email opened in Chrome, without Chrome running beforehand.
- **Copied one of my old profiles over default**. **Test was successful**, indicating that this profile was not the cause of the problem.
- Used profile manager (`$ thunderbird -ProfileManager`) to create a new profile, and copied my second old profile over it. **Tested using second profile. This test was also successful**, indicating that neither profile was the source of the orignial problem.
- Renamed profiles to same as they were before, and **copied the old Thunderbird profiles.ini over the new one**. **Test was successful**, indicating there was nothing amiss with the profiles.ini.
- **Re-enabled all my original extensions and plug-ins in Chrome**. **Test was successful**.

So the only conclusion I can come to is that there was something amiss with the Thunderbird installation, and that the re-install resolved the issue.  Fortunately, being able to easily save and replace the profiles made re-install relatively painless.