# apt-get install -f is removing packages installed by dpkg -i on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, google-chrome

I cannot install google chrome or any .deb(atom as well) package using dpkg and apt-get on **NEW Install of  Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop 64 bit**.

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 160951 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (62.0.3202.94-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
google-chrome-stable depends on gconf-service; however:
Package gconf-service is not installed.
google-chrome-stable depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5); however:
Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
   google-chrome-stable

$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 184 MB disk space will be freed.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 161054 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing google-chrome-stable (62.0.3202.94-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
```

Again :

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I am not able to solve this for any Package.
Please Help.
Thanks!

Edit (Dec 5'17):

**For Atom**

```
$ sudo dpkg -i atom-amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package atom.
(Reading database ... 160951 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack atom-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking atom (1.22.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of atom:
 atom depends on git; however:
  Package git is not installed.
 atom depends on gconf2; however:
  Package gconf2 is not installed.
 atom depends on gconf-service; however:
  Package gconf-service is not installed.
 atom depends on python; however:
  Package python is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package atom (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atom

$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  atom
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 459 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 168278 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing atom (1.22.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
```

**Hash Sum mismatch with apt-get upate**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78.6 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [78.6 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease [72.2 kB] 
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease [237 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages [1,071 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main i386 Packages [1,067 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main Translation-en [542 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [397 kB]
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [263 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/restricted amd64 Packages [8,852 B]
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/restricted i386 Packages [8,876 B]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/restricted Translation-en [2,788 B]
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe i386 Packages [8,066 kB]
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 Packages [8,103 kB]
Get:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe Translation-en [4,789 kB]
Get:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,845 kB]
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,915 kB]
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse i386 Packages [143 kB]
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse i386 Packages [143 kB]
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse i386 Packages [143 kB]
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse i386 Packages [143 kB]
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse i386 Packages [143 kB]
Err:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse i386 Packages     
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:142776 [weak]
   - SHA256:d1f9e7ec6489f3540ddd3399c345799e46d2e1213570f510ca41bd12d5b9407e
   - SHA1:16f5314466b815e49a6b53124ba88bd434304b9e [weak]
   - MD5Sum:c7b94987695731eb16b07c5bb0c8311d [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:8da861b95323d6b98fdcc24324eee84baa90aa6159cf9b7134fe81432639e14e
   - SHA1:9ecda16f6e859d480eacde0b06800c58f7d7a43e [weak]
   - MD5Sum:f8c8486e5ab253cb02209022ff3d0dc1 [weak]
   - Filesize:142776 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 18 Oct 2017 08:50:51 +0000
  Release file created at: Thu, 19 Oct 2017 12:55:45 +0000
Fetched 609 kB in 5s (114 kB/s)                                
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/multiverse/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/d1f9e7ec6489f3540ddd3399c345799e46d2e1213570f510ca41bd12d5b9407e  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:142776 [weak]
    - SHA256:d1f9e7ec6489f3540ddd3399c345799e46d2e1213570f510ca41bd12d5b9407e
    - SHA1:16f5314466b815e49a6b53124ba88bd434304b9e [weak]
    - MD5Sum:c7b94987695731eb16b07c5bb0c8311d [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:8da861b95323d6b98fdcc24324eee84baa90aa6159cf9b7134fe81432639e14e
    - SHA1:9ecda16f6e859d480eacde0b06800c58f7d7a43e [weak]
    - MD5Sum:f8c8486e5ab253cb02209022ff3d0dc1 [weak]
    - Filesize:142776 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 18 Oct 2017 08:50:51 +0000
   Release file created at: Thu, 19 Oct 2017 12:55:45 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Even apt-get is not installing.**

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

**SOLVED**

```
$ sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz
```

https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/03/21/apt-hash-sum-mismatch/

Thanks

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Comment: It's not only about Google Chrome but every .deb package

Comment: Could you add the output when trying to install any other program from the default sources?

Comment: Even apt-get install is not working

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Based on your edits my original comment is wrong in that the referenced question is not your primary problem. However your question is a likely dup of [Trouble downloading packages list due to a “Hash sum mismatch” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dpkg does not solve dependencies.
Whenever you want install an application packaged in .deb, that is not in the repositories.
I suggest you use gdebi.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install --reinstall gdebi
```

Afterwards from the file browser, right click and select install with gdebi

If apt install --reinstall gdebi is giving E: Unable to locate package gdebi, replace the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list with the following and retry installing gdebi

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://uschive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
deb-src http://uschive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-proposed restricted universe multiverse main
```

Comment: Not able to upade because of Hash Sum mismatch and apt install --reinstall gdebi is giving E: Unable to locate package gdebi

Answer (score 0):

Try 'sudo apt-get autoremove' 'sudo apt-get clean' and 'sudo apt-get autoclean' then try again the process you were realizing.

Answer (score 0):

The hash sum mismatch error has a good answer's in [Trouble downloading packages list due to a “Hash sum mismatch” error](https://askubuntu.com/a/41618/723193).

If only a few files have a hash sum mismatch, the first command can be made more specific. The basic steps are to run the following code block:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If the problems with installing chrome persist, [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) may help.