# What is the APT Line for Google Chrome

Tags: apt, google-chrome

So I'm reading [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html) from Ubuntu official docum entation, and it says we can teach the Ubuntu Software program to check for updates from third party repositories.

Well, google chrome is third party and I just need to go to `Software & Updates` and from the `Other Software` tab, we can add a repository.

[image]

What is the APT line for google chrome?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome#510186

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

All the instructions I found suggest echo'ing into some file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directly, but apt-key complains it's deprecated (on Lunar 23.04).  Using `software-properties-gtk` I was able to enter the above as the "apt line" under "Other Software -> Add..." and didn't get any warnings and chrome was able to update.