# Constancy of all installations of the same software

Tags: 19.10

i,
I am new to Ubuntu, there is a lot to learn, but it isn't easy if things are not constant.
So, can anybody explain why I find an app in /usr/share/applications on my laptop and find the same app in /snap/share/applications on my desktop.
Both computers have Ubuntu 19.10 up to date.

Comment: You didn't say what 'app' you're talking about, but on one box the app may have been installed with `snap install app` where as on the other it was with `apt install app`  (ie. snap installs installs a snap, apt install install the deb in simple terms, though some debs are wrappers that installs snaps too)

Comment: Because on the laptop you have installed the application and on the desktop you are happy enough with a snap. (A snap is similar to what on Windows we would call a "portable application", except it is less functional.)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what 'app' you're talking about, but on one box the app may have been installed with

`snap install app`

where as on the other it was with

`apt install app`

ie. `snap` installs installs a snap, `apt` install install the deb in simple terms, though some debs are wrappers that installs snaps too.

If using a software store, some 'stores' have indicators to tell you it's referring to a snap; and there are applications that list more than once (deb & snap; snaps can also offer versions were as with deb it'll always be the latest available for your release).

Comment: Also this link can be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029610/if-a-package-is-available-as-both-a-deb-and-a-snap-which-method-is-preferrable