# Conflicts installing Tomcat by snap and by apt-get?

Tags: snap, tomcat

I've installed Tomcat 9 by snap install, it is working fine.
But now I'm starting a course that begins installing Tomcat 8 and recommends to install it by apt-get, not snap. I want to do that to match version and kind of install with the course.
My question is, can I install Tomcat 8 by apt-get without conflict with Tomcat 9 snap install existing and use one or the other when I prefer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a package is available as both a deb and a snap, which method is preferrable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029610/if-a-package-is-available-as-both-a-deb-and-a-snap-which-method-is-preferrable)

Comment: @N0rbert not exactly. I ask about possible conflicts when a server is installed twice by both ways.

Comment: "and recommends to install it by apt-get, not snap" so skip that part :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without any problems. Snaps come with all needed dependencies included in the snap-package and do not interfere with deb-packages managed by `apt`.

The icons of the applications might look same, so in the first moment after installation you'll have to find out, which icon starts which application.