# What is the difference between the two versions of KeePassXC in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, keepass, keepassx, keepassxc

I'm trying to figure out which KeePass version I should install. Ubuntu Software Center doesn't make the choice any more easier.

In the description of **KeePassX**, it says (emphasis added):

> In contrast to **KeePassXC** (package keepassxc), the development pace of **KeePassX** has slowed down. It has less features, and uses an outdated version of the Qt widget. If you do not know whether you should install keepassx or keepassxc, **install keepassx instead**!

Wait, what?? **KeePassX** is fading out, has less features and is built on outdated technology, so you should use that? Well, I think I would rather choose a package that is more actively developed, has more features and is built on modern tech.

However, there seems to be two versions of **KeePassXC** in the Software Center:

- **2.6.6** (151 reviews): *"Modern, secure, and cross-platform password manager compatible with KeePass"*
- **2.6.6+dfsg.1-1~exp1** (169 reviews): *"Community-driven port of the Windows application “KeePass Password Safe”"*

Now, what is the practical difference between the two versions of **KeePassXC**, and are there really some reasons to prefer **KeePassX** instead?

I'm grateful for all the help. Trying out the different versions would be quite an undertaking, as there are plenty of relevant use-cases across different platforms.

Comment: After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04, I see KeePassX is not installed; I seem to have both KeepasXC and Keepass2 installed. I see in APT there is now: `keepass`, `keepassx` and `keepassxc` `(I don't trust Snap with anything important)`. `keepassx` identifies as an "empty transitional package". I don't know what that means exactly, so I install it, which concludes with the message `keepassx is already the newest version (2.0.3+keepassxc1).` So KeePassXC appears to be Ubuntu's choice for prior users of KeePassX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two KeePassXC versions is essentially their version number. You see two versions, because KeePassXC is available in two different package formats, as a traditional `.deb` package from the [Ubuntu software sources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) and as a [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/about) package. Typically, the Snap version will be newer than the `.deb` package. This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029610/if-a-package-is-available-as-both-a-deb-and-a-snap-which-method-is-preferrable) outlines a few of the pros and cons of each format.

Comment: Thanks vanadium! Is there an easy way to tell Snap and deb packages apart in the Software Center? The Source (always "snapcraft.io" for Snap?)? So, I guess in this case, "2.6.6" is the Snap version..?

Comment: Yes, you can see in the Software center what the source is.