# How to stop getting error message and two tabs when I ctrl + click on a link in gnome terminal

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, selenium

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I use google-chrome as my default browser. It works great when I open it from the terminal with `google-chrome` or `google-chrome-stable`. It also works great when I run my test server in pycharm and click the link - opens right up.

However, when I click on any link from the terminal, it opens up chrome in a different window (even if I already have it open) and gives me two tabs.

The first one's address is **http://extension%3D/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.KmLkmq/internal** and it says **This site can't be reached. extension%3D’s server IP address could not be found**.

The second one's address is **data:,** and it's just a blank page.

Both of them have the little bar at the top that says "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software."

This happened a little while ago and I believe it was while I was using selenium and chromedriver to open and read data from some webpages, mostly just tinkering around. I'm guessing something got stuck and now it's gonna do that forever. I've tried a few things since then, but nothing seems to work.

If I change the default browser to firefox, it still opens up these weird two pages.

Should I just try reinstalling chrome or does anyone have any other solutions?

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oSyW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! Just uninstalled and reinstalled google-chrome-stable.

`rm ~/.config/google-chrome`
`sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable`

Then I removed everything else chrome-related (cache, chromedriver, etc).

Then I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510186/832265) to reinstall the latest version of google-chrome-stable. Works great now! When I click a link from the terminal, it opens right up in chrome without the weird tabs.