# Install chrome to a specific location

Tags: software-installation, firefox, google-chrome, chromium

I followed instructions at [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) to install Chrome. For some reasons, my Selenium script was not recognising it.
I then installed Chromium and Firefox and the script worked fine. 
On further debugging, I found the issue is with the install location of these browsers.

Chromium: qa_user@jenkins:/usr/share/chromium-browser

Firefox: qa_user@jenkins:/usr/share/Firefox

[image]

Chrome:

[image]
[image]

How can I get Chrome installed in /usr/share/Google-Chrome-Stable like Chromium and Mozilla?

Comment: Probably, you should solve the issue at the level of your script. Not at the level as to where programs are installed. Google chrome is not open source, so it will be difficult to control the packaging and installation yourself.

Comment: That makes sense. Just wanted to check if I can get the same location for all browsers so that I can use a generic script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding the following arguments to the selenium driver

```
--remote-debugging-port=<port>
```

For Example,

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}) 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox") 

chromeOptions.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # this

chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-gpu") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("start-maximized") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chromeOptions.add_argument("user-data-dir=.\cookies\\test") 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions) 
driver.get("https://google.com/") 
driver. Quit()
```