# How to update Chrome in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: google-chrome

What is the right way to update chrome on Ubuntu 20.04. My installation was with .deb file

I started getting update chrome warning messages on my chrome now. I do not want to uninstall and then reinstall to save my bookmarks and saved credentials.

is Google Sync a safe option for this?

Comment: Chrome should get updates automatically when you update your system. It seems that you disabled that.

Comment: Google sync is good for bookmarks and extensions.  If by credentials you mean passwords, I myself would not use any browser password keeper, but do use a separate password manager.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

These are a couple of ways to update Google Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04 when the installation is done through the .deb file:

1. Open Software Updater. Select and install the available Google Chrome update.
2. Through Terminal. Type `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: In my first try, the 2nd command failed as I haven't noticed that the command wraps on the next line.

Comment: Do not forget to close / reopen Chrome after the update has installed

Comment: google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (91.0.4472.77-1) -- but still chrome issues warning that Upgrade needed.

Comment: This answer did not work for me like the other reply above that has 8 up votes. The next solution below with not nearly as many upvotes solved it

Comment: Worked for me, on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: If the second command fails because of a lock fail, you can try "sudo killall apt apt-get" and then retry.

Comment: @zawy, I installed chrome using deb file and whenever there is an update for the chrome (a warning message added to Chrome browser for update), I use the solution given above, and It always works without close the browser or restart laptop.

Answer (score 46):

Hope [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/510186/349837) helps:

Add Key:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Set repository:

```
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Install package:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: In ubuntu 20 you can write just apt instead of apt-get

Comment: This solution worked where the solution with a lot more upvotes did not.

Comment: This solve the problem on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 31):

context: you've already installed Chrome and can't seem to update it - where the command line tells you that you already have the latest, Chrome keeps complaining you need to update - and when you relaunch Chrome it fails to update.

Try the following...

Check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

If it looks like this:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
# deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

uncomment the last line, so that it looks like this:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Then do:

```
sudo apt update
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Thank you! Can confirm this is the answer that worked. After uncommenting that line I was able to `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable` and it actually worked.

Comment: Thank you, worked for me as well

Comment: Clear and straightforward, this should be the accepted answer !!!

Comment: This worked indeed. The entry contained a comment in my case that the repository was disabled during the upgrade from my previous version to 22.04. Enabling it again allowed updates as part of the regular update and upgrade procedure (the second step of (re-)installing `google-chrome-stable` was not needed).

Answer (score 9):

1. Download .deb (for example) from: https://www.google.com/chrome/
2. In your download directory, you need to find: `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
3. Run: `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`.

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect and works well for me"