# How to update Chrome version 81 to lastest version 85 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: updates, 20.04, google-chrome

Google Chrome shows to me the notification that version 81 is out of date.

I tried to update Google Chrome using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

or

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
```

But the result is the same:

```
google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (81.0.4044.92-1)
```

Then I used this decision but nothing changed:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1276010/1067426

How can I update Google Chrome? What's wrong?

I do not want to uninstall and reinstall from .deb. I think there is another way

Comment: Simply download `.deb` package from https://www.google.com/chrome/ and install it with `dpkg -i ...deb`. It will automatically add the PPA and update automatically in the future.

Comment: When installing most third party programs, Ubuntu usually asks if you want it updated with the rest of the system.  You probably missed it or said no, which is why it is not updating.  Need someone else to say if it can be changed after.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Setup key with:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Setup repository with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

Setup package with:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable


Package                 Version
google-chrome-beta      86.0.4240.42-1
google-chrome-unstable  87.0.4263.3-1
google-chrome-unstable  87.0.4259.3-1
google-chrome-beta      86.0.4240.30-1
google-chrome-stable    85.0.4183.102-1
```