# Chrome says I should update but apt-get says I have the latest version

Tags: apt, 20.04, google

Chrome says I should update but apt-get says I have the latest version. When I run "sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable" I get "google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (90.0.4430.93-1)." I am running Ubuntu 20.04. How can I stop the Google nag screen to update?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) as the latest Chrome version is 92.0.4515.107-1, so you have disabled Google's repository.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, although apt tells me that I have 90.0.4430.212-1 and claims that it is the latest version.  I'm assuming that the google-chrome-stable package hasn't been updated to match Google's latest release.  Also, when I click on "Update" in the browser, and then "Chrome is out of date", I get "Can't update Chrome" and a suggestion to "Reinstall Chrome"

Comment: I'm having the same issue Brian describes

Comment: It's a month later, and I'm still having this problem on one of my 20.04 machines.  However, ubuntu's google-chrome-stable has updated to 92.0.4515.159-1 on my other 20.04 machines and won't upgrade on this machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 as well and `apt show google-chrome-stable` didn't find anything. That probably means that you installed Chrome from a third party apt repository which contains an outdated version of Chrome, or manually from a .deb file.

If you don't mind snaps you can install the latest, stable [Chromium](https://snapcraft.io/chromium) (92.0.4515.107) with `sudo snap install chromium`.

Comment: paul@CarolineEycks:~$ apt show google-chrome-stable
Package: google-chrome-stable
Version: 90.0.4430.93-1
Status: install ok installedpaul@CarolineEycks:~$ sudo snap install chromium
[sudo] password for paul: 
snap "chromium" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

Comment: Ok, so you have installed both versions of Chrome. Try to launch _Chromium_ instead of _Google Chrome_. You can just search for it in the activities overview. If Chromium is outdated as well, run `sudo snap refresh`.