# How to install Google Chrome version 90 for ubuntu?

Tags: google

Want to install Google Chrome version 90.0.4430.212. Where cam i get it or any apt install command?

Comment: You need that specific version [from May 10, 2021](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/05/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html)? Or will the most recent version also be acceptable?

Comment: Need that specific version 90 only! Which released in April!!

Comment: Its need for some performance testing

Comment: Unless someone has the .deb file saved, you have to contact Google support and ask them to give the correct package

Comment: Package.deb : chromium (90.0.4430.212-1) : https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/chromium/download ..... Ref.  https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/chromium   + https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/chromium-common ........ ( and my 'Jun 2021' backup https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HsuZQNyKNq9L1XcE1clacFLwiRK9gDS3?usp=sharing )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for that chrome version specifically or just how to install Chrome?

If you are looking how to install chrome just download the .deb and install it that way.
https://www.google.com/chrome/

If you are looking for that specific version, as far as I know google doesn't make them available. But you can find all the releases through 3rd party's.
https://chromium.cypress.io

ADDED: "https://chromium.cypress.io/linux/stable/90.0.4430.212"