# google chrome out of date

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

I am running ubuntu 20.04.

Google Chrome worked fine for a year or so, then recently I began getting messages ‘google can't update, relaunch’; I did and downloaded and installed the latest version but it still displayed the old version (92) with the same message.

Should I have deleted the old version before downloading the new one?

Comment: Well how did you install the latest version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall the current version of chrome you are using and download the latest version of chrome from official website from here [Chrome Download](https://www.google.com/intl/en_in/chrome/)