Google Chrome says "Chrome is out of date" but apt says "google-chrome-stable is already the newest version"
This has been happening for a good few months, but it's definitely a change in behaviour in the past year.  Every time a new version of Chrome comes out, I get a message in Chrome to say the update has failed and I should restart the browser to install the update.  Restarting makes no difference, of course.
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable returns "google-chrome-stable is already the newest version"
apt show google-chrome-stable shows the same version number as Chrome does, confirming it's the version apt thinks it is.
These all show my installed (and apparently up to date) version as v129.whatever but the current stable release according to Google is v131.whatever.  Does it just take ages from Google releasing a new version to it appearing in the repository, or is something broken?  If it does just take time, is there a way to disable the message popping up in Chrome all the time to say it's out of date?
It's only a minor annoyance, as I use Opera for most things, but still use Chrome for some websites that "don't support" Opera.
Opera updates just fine, and I noticed today that Chromium updated via Discover, so it does seem to be peculiar to Chrome.
I'm using Kubuntu 24.10, but the behaviour is unchanged from 24.04 at least.
Edit 1: The suggested similar question is one I looked at prior to posting this one.  The marked answer to that one says apt show google-chrome-stable doesn't find any results, suggesting it was not installed from the repository.  Mine does show an output with version number and maintainer info, so presumably isn't the same problem.
That said, apt show does show Apt-Manual-Installed: yes so could this be the issue?  If so, how do I install it properly so the package manager keeps it updated?
Edit 2: Looking at other posts/answers, I've recalled how I have been installing/updating.  Each time I get this alert, I go to the Chrome download site, download the latest x64 .deb package and install it with sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
This presumably explains the manual install flag from apt show but I'm led to believe this should also automagically add the Google repository for updates.  Is there a way I can check that part has worked?
Edit 3: Output from sudo apt update seemingly showing no Google repos:
flim@flim:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for flim:
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-updates InRelease [126 kB]
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-updates InRelease [126 kB]
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-backports InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-updates/main amd64 Packages [62.7 kB]
Get:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-updates/main amd64 Packages [62.7 kB]
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-updates/universe amd64 Packages [28.1 kB]
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-security InRelease
Fetched 406 kB in 6s (65.9 kB/s)
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
flim@flim:~$


This question is similar to: Chrome says I should update but apt-get says I have the latest version. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375462/google-chrome-out-of-date

Thanks @graham. I did see that one before posting, but I get a different result from apt show so believe it to be a different issue.  Please see edit in main post.

First you need to figure out if you installed a deb package or a snap package or something else. apt only works on deb packages. Then you need to use the correct package manager (apt, snap, etc) to determine the current version that you should have.

Thanks @user535733 - I installed via .deb, detail added to main post under Edit 2

Run sudo apt update. Please edit your question to show us the complete output.

Seems like an inconsistence between Chrome's own update mechanism and package manager updates? I would expect that package updates will be delayed with regard to upstream updates, so if updates from package manager work OK, I would suggest just turning off Chrome's own update mechanism.

Oh, I have just noticed that you are updating manually. No, dpkg -i does not add anything to repositories, it just installs the package. Unless the package installation script includes adding a repository (which it shouldn't in my opinion), you have to add the repository yourself.

@user535733 and @raj - see Edit 3 showing no repo for Google.  Can you confirm that dpkg -i does not add the repo?  That wasn't my understanding.

dpkg -i installs whatever package you tell it to install. And nothing else. That's why I don't recommend using that method. Regardless of whether or not something was supposed to add a repo, now you know it's not there. If you Google "chrome ubuntu repo" you will find instructions to add the Google repo so your Chrome will update automatically through apt.

Thanks for the edit @user535733

I extracted the package and looked at the postinst executable and that does indeed add the repo (or it's supposed to).  I'll look for the instructions to add it manually, thanks.

Gah! Now I have two Chrome repos and one of them is an old 32-bit, but I can't tell which is which.  Sources.list.d contains two Google files: google-chrome.sources and google.list - anyone know which one to get rid of to lose the deprecated 32-bit repo?

Thanks to everyone who commented, and particularly user535733 for their input (feel free to add an answer and I'll happily mark it as the winner).
I had installed Google Chrome from the .deb package available from Google's Chrome download site and then using the command sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb which was the default download location for me (yours will likely be somewhere else).
Reviewing the contents of that package, it is supposed to add the repository as part of the post-installation tasks (postinst in the package) but, for whatever reason, that had not worked on my system.  As such, I had to manually add the repository.  To do so, I used the following commands, starting with adding the PSK:
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
I did receive a message that apt-key add is no longer supported, but it appears to have worked.  I then needed to add the actual repo:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
Initially, the instructions I followed did not include the [arch=amd64] bit, so I actually had to redo that step.
sudo apt update now shows the Chrome repo and I am able to upgrade using either sudo apt upgrade or via KDE Discover.

As per the answers in Can not update chrome in ubuntu on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange the Google chrome repository files might still have existed on the PC, but that an upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 for some reason disabled the repository by a combination of renaming files / commenting out contents.

I cannot reply to your answer but you should consider to use the new mechanism instead of relying on apt-key. The problem with apt-key is that basically all keys are put in a global store and as long as one of the keys matches for any of your repositories, it is considered valid. This poses a security risk, as a compromised key could potentially lead to untrusted packages being installed.
Nowadays the keys are put to separate files and for each repository only a specific key file is used.
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.gpg >/dev/null

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'


Should be
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

Yes, there was an comma too many between arch= and signed-by=, fixed it in my answer. Thanks!
