# Google chrome won`t install via any tool

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, google-chrome

I am trying to install google chrome for Ubuntu 20.04.
I have loaded .deb file from official website into **~/Downloads** and ran

```
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && sudo apt update
```

But it does not appear in applications and command **google-chrome** is not available via cli.

The output of **apt install ...** is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'google-chrome-stable' instead of './google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/89,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 286 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 201578 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-stable_95.0.4638.69-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (95.0.4638.69-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (95.0.4638.69-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-w
ww-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gno
me-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/goo
gle-chrome (google-chrome) in auto mode
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
```

What problem it can be?

Files google-chrome and google-chrome-stable but they are not executable.

`sudo chmod +x ./google-chrome-stable` does not make any changes

Sorry if it it is a known issue, but I can`t find any solution here.

Comment: It installed. Just hit the SUPER key and type "chrome". Or, the CLI is "google-chrome-stable".

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -L google-chrome-stable | grep bin/` and `which google-chrome-stable`? Have you tried to find Google Chrome in desktop environment menu? What is happened when you execute `google-chrome-stable`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Comment: @N0rbert `dpkg -L google-chrome-stable | grep bin/` outputs `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` and `which google-chrome-stable` outputs nothing
If I run `google-chrome-stable` or `google-chrome` cli says that there is no such command. If I prefix this commands with `sudo ..` it outputs  `ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported.`

Comment: @heynnema It does not exist either in the menu or in the command line

Comment: You should not run it as root. What is your desktop environment? Are you running on Xorg or Wayland? Do you have other more serious problems with this system?

Comment: @N0rbert No, I have this issue only with google chrome. Tried this OS image on another PC and all works fine. This is a common system on my laptop. This is my screenfetch output:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.11.0-40-generic
Shell: sudo
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
GTK Theme: Adwaita [GTK3]
Disk: 38G / 52G (78%)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx @ 8x 2,1GHz
GPU: AMD/ATI

So I need to execute sudo su before any installation or what? Sorry, I am new to linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131455/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-denis-gorbunov).