# How to find out what version of a package is in an apt repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome, github

I'm running a GitHub Action that's not seeing the latest Google Chrome version (96) which was released 1,5 days ago, and instead claims that a version before (95) is the newest version available already.

**My question here to you is: how can I check the apt repository (it seems to use [azure.archive.ubuntu.com](http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com))  it's using to see if the problem is *there*, to see what version of google-chrome-stable is listed there?** That is, I *suspect* it's there, but don't know how to check. From there on out I should be able to troubleshoot my *actual* problem (that my end-to-end selenium tests are failing because of an outdated Chrome version).

Some more relevant details:

My [most recently failed build](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/runs/4230814275?check_suite_focus=true) shows this Ubuntu version for the action:

```
Operating System
  Ubuntu
  20.04.3
  LTS
Virtual Environment
  Environment: ubuntu-20.04
  Version: 20211108.1
  Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu20/20211108.1/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md
  Image Release: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/releases/tag/ubuntu20%2F20211108.1
```

I try to update Chrome in that container using:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
google-chrome --version
```

Which unfortunately responds with:

```
Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease [10.5 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:7 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1344 kB]
Get:8 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [276 kB]
Get:9 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.5 kB]
Get:10 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [569 kB]
Get:11 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [81.6 kB]
Get:12 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [528 B]
Get:13 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [876 kB]
Get:14 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [190 kB]
Get:15 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [19.5 kB]
Get:16 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [24.5 kB]
Get:17 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [616 B]
Get:18 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [6588 B]
Get:19 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 Packages [111 kB]
Get:20 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [580 B]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [987 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [183 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [8880 B]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [526 kB]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [75.4 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [528 B]
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [653 kB]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [107 kB]
Get:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [12.9 kB]
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [21.9 kB]
Get:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [540 B]
Fetched 6430 kB in 2s (2633 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (95.0.4638.69-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
Google Chrome 95.0.4638.69
```

How can I find out what version of google-chrome-stable is listed in http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com? How do I navigate the structure of those web resources? The browser interface you get when you go there is... not intuitive.

Please "teach me how to fish": what's going on here? Where can I read up on the structure of the online resources that `apt-get update` uses? (I know there's [another question on how to get Google Chrome updated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) and that should work for me too, but in this question I just want to learn about interpreting the sources.)

Comment: You have removed the google repo. Install Chrome from a deb file, it will restore it.

Comment: In general https://packages.ubuntu.com for official packages and `apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable` for any package.

Comment: Ubuntu does not have permission to distribute Google Chrome (Google's decision, not ours). It is therefore not in the Ubuntu repositories, which is why you are having trouble finding it there.

Comment: Just point a Ubuntu docker image or VM or something to your azure repos and use `apt-cache`. It'll do the parsing for you.