# chrome update (20.04.3 LTS)

Tags: updates, google-chrome

The Ubuntu Software package manager doesn't seem to help me do this...
Chrome claims I have:
Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and requires a "Relaunch" - but this fails. Actually it appears to succeed, but 15 minutes later it tells you it has not, and asks you to do it again.

Comment: Open Updates and install, that should be all. If it mentions an error then you need to do something about it. If not it's just a matter of keeping the system updated.

Answer (score -1):

After some investigation, I reckon the simplest answer is not to try to update, but to remove and then download the latest stable version from:
https://www.google.com/chrome/

So, basically, don't follow instructions (especially from Chrome) to update, because that will take you down an endless stream of rabbit holes which will waste a lot of time an achieve very little. In my experience.

But I'm sure the command-line instructions here, which use the ppa for
google-chrome-stable ->

[How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

...work fine.

Comment: Google Chrome's installation adds its own repository to the software sources. From then on Chrome is updated alongside all the other updates, and **updating is something you SHOULD do regularly**. The Updates app is for that exact purpose - as already commented and ignored - and typically when there are important/critical security updates it'll just popup and ask you what to do. DO NOT IGNORE IT! What you describe here is a disservice to anyone reading it.