# How do I install Chrome?

Tags: command-line

How can I download Chrome? I have tried downloading it using Mozilla unsuccessfully.

I don't know if I can't download it because I was a Windows user before.

Comment: this source is available  both using link or wget as `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`   then install it from the dpkg or apt-get commands, or from the graphical installer (will ask your root password in both cases)

Comment: "*All to no avail*" is not a clear description of what occurred, what you saw and experienced, and what errors you might have seen. Those details would be very useful.

Comment: Please search before asking.  This question is an exact duplicate of [How to Install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/q/510056).

Answer (score -1):

Try chromium in the Ubuntu Appstore, as it is very similar to chrome. if you want chrome, then try downloading a different browser from the appstore, then download it from that browser. Double-click the file, and it should open in the software installer app, and if not, then right click it, view in folder, then right click the file, press open with other application, press software installer, and then it should download.