# When I download Google Chrome, it does not auto launch the installation startup

Tags: google-chrome, google

When I download Google Chrome, it does not auto launch the installation startup. It just stops after the download is complete. The download looks to be complete but does not continue with the installation. Please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You must have downloaded a .deb file of Google Chrome.

Open a terminal where the downloaded .deb file is located and run the command

```
sudo apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```