# Help with installing application

Tags: software-installation

How do I install Google CHrome on Ubuntu, I am only 10 years old, I just installed Ubuntu on my Dad's computer without his permission, how Do I install GOogle Chreome?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: See this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/510079/124466