# Help with installing the Chrome web browser (22.04.2 LTS)

Tags: google-chrome, tar

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my computer a few hours ago. For a few days, I tried to do an install so I could dual boot between Ubuntu & Windows 10.  But I had failure after failure, so I gave up.  I formatted my Samsung SS drive to one large partition and did a ubuntu only install which seems to be working fine as far as I can tell.

I launch Firefox.  After it was launched, I clicked on Firefox again to have two version of it on screen, but it did not work.  I did this often in Windows.  Guess this will not work under Ubuntu?

So I googled Chrome and found a version that is supported under Linux and Ubuntu and down loaded it.  But I was unable to install it.

My download of Chrome looks like this:

control.tar.xz  14.0 kb Tar Archive
data,tar.zx    93.8MB  tar Archive
debian-binary  4 bytes  type - unknown 24March 2023, 14:40

I am guessing .tar is maybe like a Zip file & I need a tool to uncompresse it??  I clicked on all three of the above and nothing installed.

What is my next step?

Thanks to all who have helped me.

mraroid in Oregon

Comment: You downloaded the wrong file. Go to https://www.google.com/chrome/ from Firefox in Ubuntu. click on the big blue **Download Chrome** button. You should see a popup window (you may have to allow popups in Firefox) that says "Please select your download package" Select **64bit .deb (for Debian/Ubuntu)**. Then click the **Accept and Install** button. This may not actually install Chrome, but just download the file. Double clicking on the downloaded file should do the actual installation.

Comment: Addressing your motivation to try Chrome: You can always use Ctrl+N to open a new window of either Chromium or Firefox. And with that you keep using open-source tools, of which Chrome isn't one. :)

Comment: Right click the Firefox icon to see the context menu and select **Open a New Window**.

Comment: Thank you for your help user68186.  That worked perfect!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 8):

### Download Google Chrome

You can download the latest version of Google Chrome from their official website. For this, you can use the command-line with wget:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

This will download the .deb package of Google Chrome for 64-bit systems, which is standard for most modern systems. If you have a different architecture, you'll need to get the appropriate package from Google Chrome's download page.

### Install Google Chrome

To install the package you've just downloaded, run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

During the installation process, it's possible that you might encounter some dependency errors. If this happens, you can fix it and complete the installation by running:

```
 sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

### Launch Google Chrome

Once installed, you can launch Google Chrome from the application menu or from the terminal using:

```
google-chrome-stable
```

#### Optional: Create a Desktop Shortcut (if it doesn't automatically exist)

If, for some reason, a desktop shortcut isn't created, you can manually create one:

Navigate to the applications directory:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/
```

Copy the google-chrome.desktop file to your desktop:

```
cp google-chrome.desktop ~/Desktop/
```

Now, you'll have a shortcut on your desktop that you can double-click to start Google Chrome.

That's it!

Google Chrome should now be installed on your Ubuntu system. Remember to periodically check for updates, as Chrome updates frequently to provide new features and security patches.

Same you can do using graphical method as well if you are not comfortable with command.

Read this [article on imaginelinux](https://www.imaginelinux.com/install-chrome-on-ubuntu/) to find more . This should work, if you still face issue there is another thred on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) to resolve this.