# Google Chrome crashes immediately after launch

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, chromium, crash

I have an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS system. Google Chrome 118.0.5993.117 was working fine but I got an update from Software Updater (among other updates Google Chrome was also listed) after which Chrome crashes (exits) as soon as I open it.

I installed MS Edge, but it shows the same behavior. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome using the `.deb` package, but the problem still persists. It also does the same thing. However, Firefox  works just fine.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try to install using this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) and check whether the problem still persists or not.